# How to get around the frustrating XFF behavior in HAProxy

Tags: haproxy

tl;dr; how to APPEND (replace-value or replace-header) to the X-Forwarded-For header when it is received by HAProxy as a comma separated list from downstream?

By default HAProxy does not append to the X-Forwarded-For header like NGINX does and instead creates a duplicate header with a new value - yes according to RFC they are allowed. Now my problem is that this behavior is not acceptable to my upstream applications. I need to work around this.

My HAProxy receives the X-Forwarded-For header from downstream as: "X-Forward-For: presumed client ip, edge reverse proxy ip, ingress controller ip" next in  line is auth gateway (it adds some specific headers) and then comes HAProxy and backend web servers. I need to append the auth gateway ip as the fourth entry to the XFF list in HAProxy.

I have tried the following in the appropriate backend definition:

`http-request replace-value X-Forwarded-For (.*) " %[hdr(x-forwarded-for)], %[src]"`

Results in "X-Forwarded-For: ingress controller ip, auth gateway ip, ingress controller ip, auth gateway ip, ingress controller ip, auth gateway ip"

`http-request replace-header X-Forwarded-For (.*) " %[hdr(x-forwarded-for)], %[src]"`

Results in "X-Forwarded-For: ingress controller ip, auth gateway ip"

`http-request replace-value X-Forwarded-For ^ " %[hdr(x-forwarded-for)], %[src]`

Results in "X-Forwarded-For:ingress controller ip, auth gateway ip, ingress controller ip, auth gateway ip, ingress controller ip, auth gateway ip"

`http-request replace-header X-Forwarded-For ^ " %[hdr(x-forwarded-for)], %[src]`

Results in "X-Forwarded-For: ingress controller ip, auth gateway ip"

I initially thought that there is some 200 IQ HAProxy developer logic pertaining to XFF header and tested using a differently named duplicate header X-FF-1 which contains the downstream XFF values ...

`http-request replace-value X-Forwarded-For (.*) " %[hdr(x-ff-1)], %[src]`

Results in "X-Forwarded-For: ingress controller ip, auth gateway ip, ingress controller ip, auth gateway ip, ingress controller ip, auth gateway ip"

`http-request replace-header X-Forwarded-For ^ " %[hdr(x-ff-1)], %[src]"`

Results in "X-Forwarded-For: ingress controller ip, auth gateway ip"

... but no dice.

I have no idea how to get around this shortcoming. It might be a simple regex fix, but I think there something totally broken in how HAProxy handles headers when they are presented as a comma separated list. In the XFF case everything but the right most value in the comma separated list is discarded.

Also, I know using the XFF header for client ip is sketchy but I have zero to none influence over my company's software development team.

Comment: if you use only this forwardfor in default options, I remember it will append

Comment: Nope, the default behaviour for option forwardfor is to append to the headers by creating a new one so it will look like; X-Forwarded-For: presumed client ip and somewhere down the line another header X-Forwarded-For: proxy1 ip. I will post the exact rewrite and replace lines in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append to a comma delimited list you can use the following i.e if you have "X-Forwarded-For: presumed client ip, proxy1" and want to append "proxy2", after

```
http-request replace-header X-Forwarded-For ^ "%[req.fhdr(x-forwarded-for)], %[src]"
```

You get "X-Forwarded-For: presumed client ip, proxy1, proxy2".

For appending "proxy1" to a single "X-Forwarded-For: presumed client ip" you can use

```
http-request replace-value X-Forwarded-for ^ "%[hdr(x-forwarded-for)], %[src]"
```